# MVC Routing, Register a specific area rather than all

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am creating MVC application where I have several domains and depending on the domain it will go to a specific area.

when the application starts the application calls the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`
is there a way to register one specific area rather than all??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `RegisterAllAreas` is primarily for registering an area's routes. If you don't want those routes registered, you could set an appSetting or similar config, and just use that variable to decide whether or not to register the area's routes. Why exactly are you looking for this functionality?

Answer (score -1):

read about the [area registration class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.arearegistration%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) I hope it will help to accomplish this task.
see the example:

```
public class BlogAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
public override string AreaName
{
    get
    {
        return "Blog";
    }
}

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Blog_default",
        "Blog/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
}
}
```